# Assigning SelectionMode to Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGrid" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsRightTapEnabled="False" RightTapped="MyGrid_RightTapped" BorderThickness="0" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="290" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="#596A82">
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Margin="10,5,10,5" Text="{Binding Brand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#BDC3CD"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="10,4,10,5" Text="{Binding Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#BDC3CD"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And i have a button, when it clicks i need to assign SelectionMode property in GridView to multiple.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyGrid.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
}
```

But it's not working and showing error like this.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionMode' to
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ListViewSelectionMode` instead of `SelectionMode`

```
MyGrid.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
```